# Conditional Type without using As

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a variable named `movies` that can take the form of two shapes defined as the following interfaces:

```
interface BaseMovie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

interface MultiSearchResult extends BaseMovie {
  media_type: "movie" | "tv" | "person";
}
```

I know that when another variable, `triggeredSearch` is true, the shape will be `MultiSearchResult`. The shape will be `BaseMovie` when `triggeredSearch` is false.

While using this to render each item

```
<ul>
  {movies.map((movie, i) => (
    <li key={i}>{!triggeredSearch ? movie.title : movie.media_type}</li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

I receive the following warning:

> Property 'media_type' does not exist on type 'BaseMovie | MultiSearchResult'.
> Property 'media_type' does not exist on type 'BaseMovie'.ts(2339)

Is there a way, outside of using the `as` keyword (i.e. `(movie as MultiSearchResult).media_type`), to declare that a `movie` is a `MultiSearchResult` when `triggeredSearch` is true?

A full example can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-benz-fibwr?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: What's the type of `movies`? Remember that off-site links are not a substitute for putting **all necessary code here on-site**. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Comment: You can provide a runnable full example here on-site using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript can't narrow the type of a variable based on the value of another variable, but it *can* narrow the type of a union based on one of the union's members. So if you can put `triggeredSearch` and `movies` in the same data structure, you can use a discriminated union to distinguish things:

```
type Example =
  { triggeredSearch: true, movies: null | MultiSearchResult[] }
  |
  { triggeredSearch: false, movies: null | BaseMovie[] };

declare const data: Example;

// Side note: Using thea rray index as the key an anti-pattern if the
// arrays contents ever change, more here:
// https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318
const items = data.triggeredSearch
  ? data.movies?.map((movie, i) => <li key={i}>{movie.media_type}</li>)
  : data.movies?.map((movie, i) => <li key={i}>{movie.title}</li>);

const result = <ul>{items}</ul>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgCEUBnJAWQgDdhmAb3Jw4wACYAuONQCuIAEb0KomMBgAbJNPYwoNAOYUAvpRp0GTOF1ka1AZVRQ0AC2Ttb8JAA861ceysHNx8AnDCoiBI4sAoAPowAJ5g2gQgoUj4cAA+BDC8Wbn4KVDsENRk5KbkSSlwAKLeKOBacAC8IuFwesAGBvTRjijOLtJ6skgANHDp-Ejs0nIaGjnWnsBDI+6eANoAunCmotmdgt36fQPim67SjBqc07MCCzK2K7lsnDxz+4cU5HESDQGmGzDQ5V0cHEKBgKGkjWaYC0AIA9Ki4PYJMxqBA6NIAKrsQzdFyoOBQKAoRJifw+OAcUnMADWSBpKGoDNowAAtGBYRZOcBMEzyOiGZTqYEIbQkLRAkhePQ4K4Of0ntBmGSiJIxRiXDAYGAFuicAoaJBmdBqIkAHRRGLyW0QkComhA7w8jhenmsxI84DsL3UYNqPkC+ghpAABgAzAAWACcKGBSFjAEYABzkGVQ9RIECBNrQ2EoW09S5Ea5OVydAD8Jbh9oy7Dr9pQYAAFJ3nlMxABKdoAPjgAB4NMA4H62oJgMYh4Je-borEEskkMZR6iJ0P+51pDCm73W+2uz2MtNgIO2iPx5Pp7P54uMuX1FpN9vgLuAbn4EQPHY7RjrYC75oWH4gRQQA)

If you can't, you can use a type assertion function rather than `as`, which has the advantage of giving you a runtime error if the assertion is false:

```
function assertMultiSearchResult(movie: BaseMovie): asserts movie is MultiSearchResult {
    if (!("media_type" in movie)) {
        throw new Error(`Given 'movie' is not a 'MultiSearchResult');
    }
}
```

Then:

```
<ul>
    {movies?.map((movie, i) => {
        let content: string;
        if (triggeredSerach) {
            assertMultiSearchResult(movie);
            content = movie.media_type;
        } else {
            content = movie.title;
        }
        return <li key={i}>{content}</li>;
    })}
</ul>
```

More long-winded, but also more typesafe.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript doesn't understand your business context.

Why not just set the `media_type` property to optional, and type your `movies` state to `MultiSearchResult[]` only?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface BaseMovie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

interface MultiSearchResult extends BaseMovie {
  media_type?: "movie" | "tv" | "person";
}

export default function App() {
  const [triggeredSearch, setTriggeredSearch] = useState(false);
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MultiSearchResult[]>([
    { id: 1, title: "Avengers" },
    { id: 2, title: "Eternals" }
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMovies([
      { id: 1, title: "Avengers", media_type: "movie" },
      { id: 2, title: "Eternals", media_type: "movie" }
    ]);
  }, [triggeredSearch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setTriggeredSearch(true)}>Trigger Search</button>
      <ul>
        {movies.map((movie, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{!triggeredSearch ? movie.title : movie.media_type}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```